# Matplotlib：Legend python with no show in the legend information, only a transparent square showed

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

```
x = range(11, 31)
y_1 = [1,0,1,1,2,4,3,2,3,4,4,5,6,5,4,3,3,1,1,1]
y_2 = [1,0,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

# 图形大小
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8), dpi = 80)

# 设置x轴刻度
x_label = ["{}岁".format(i) for i in x]
plt.xticks(list(x), x_label, fontproperties = my_font) # 显示中文刻度

# 绘制网格
plt.grid(alpha = 0.4) 

# 添加图例
plt.legend(prop = my_font, loc = "upper left")

# Execution 
plt.plot(x, y_1, label = "Mine")
plt.plot(x, y_2, label = "Him")


# Display
plt.show()
```

This is the code for legends showing in Python matplotlib, and I wanna show the legend, but the result is that there is no show at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `plt.legend` **after** plotting the curves:

```
# first
plt.plot(x, y_1, label = "Mine")
plt.plot(x, y_2, label = "Him")

# next
plt.legend(loc = "upper left")
```

output (smaller size):

[image]